# Derivation of Restricted Boltzmann Machine Conditional Probability

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, deep-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I was reading Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville's *Deep Learning* and in [Chapter 20](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/generative_models.html) there is a derivation of the conditional probability $P(h_j=1|\boldsymbol{v})$, the conditional probability of the $j^{th}$ hidden unit being on given a data vector $\boldsymbol{v}$:

[image]

Note that $Z'$ is a normalizing constant, and $\tilde{P}(E)$ is the unnormalized probability of event $E$.

The derivation of 20.7 through 20.11 is clear to me, but for  equation 20.13, **we assume the inside of our product, $\exp{\{c_j h_j + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,j} \boldsymbol{h}_j\}}$, is exactly equal to our (unnormalized) unit probability $\tilde{P}(h_j|\boldsymbol{v})$.**

(This is described in the paragraph between 20.11 and 20.12, and we evaluate this $\tilde{P}(h_j|\boldsymbol{v})$ for $h_j = 0$ and $h_j = 1$ to get equation 20.13.)

---

My question is, *why can we make this assumption?*

The argument the paper seems to make is that because $P(\boldsymbol{h}|\boldsymbol{v})$ takes on the form $\frac{1}{Z'} \prod_{j=1}^{n_h} f(h_j)$, we can safely assume $f(h_j)$ must be our probability for each unit, $\tilde{P}(h_j|\boldsymbol{v})$.

I understand that $P(\boldsymbol{h}|\boldsymbol{v})$ must equal $\frac{1}{Z'} \prod_{j=1}^{n_h} \tilde{P}(h_j|\boldsymbol{v})$, but if we are given the equation $P(\boldsymbol{h}|\boldsymbol{v}) = \frac{1}{Z'} \prod_{j=1}^{n_h} f(h_j)$, couldn't there be several functions $f$ that fit this criterion? $f$ wouldn't necessarily have to be $\tilde{P}(h_j|\boldsymbol{v})$, would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20.7-11 give us first, 
$$
p(\mathbf{h}|\mathbf{v}) \propto \prod_j\exp{\{c_j h_j + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,j} h_j\}}.
$$
After summing out any unwanted variables, we get for any $i$,
\begin{align*}
p(h_i | \mathbf{v}) &\propto \sum_{\mathbf{h} : \mathbf{h_i} = h_i} \prod_j\exp{\{c_j h_j + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,j} h_j\}} \\
&= \sum_{\mathbf{h} : \mathbf{h_i} = h_i} \left[ \prod_{j \neq i} \exp{\{c_j h_j + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,j} h_j\}}  \exp{\{c_i h_i + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h_i\}} \right] \\
&= \exp{\{c_i h_i + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h_i\}} \sum_{\mathbf{h} : \mathbf{h_i} = h_i} \left[ \prod_{j \neq i} \exp{\{c_j h_j + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,j} h_j\}}   \right] \\
&\propto \exp{\{c_i h_i + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h_i\}},
\end{align*}
assuming all the sums we take are finite.

You ask if $\exp{\{c_i h_i + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h_i\}}$ constitutes an unnormalized probability distribution. The answer is yes, and these have a special name. Your link calls them "Energy Based Models" (same as exponential family models?). It is easy to see that

$$
p(h_i|\mathbf{v}) = \frac{ \exp{\{c_i h_i + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h_i\}} }{ \sum_h \exp{\{c_i h + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h\}} }
$$
because $0 < \sum_h \exp{\{c_i h + \boldsymbol{v}^\top \boldsymbol{W}_{:,i} h\}} < \infty$.

Comment: What happens if more than one $i$ satisfies $f(h_i) \neq \tilde{P}(h_i|\boldsymbol{v})$?

Comment: @AliasUser I'm going to change this answer a lot. Give me one moment

Comment: @AliasUser ok there. Basically it doesn't matter if you call $\tilde{P}(h_j|\mathbf{v})$ an unnormalized probability or not. The steps to get the marginal are still the same.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer -- it's incredibly well written. I follow all of it except the "summing out" part. Does the first equation directly imply the second?

Comment: @AliasUser I added some more steps. How's that

Comment: Ohh, thank you! That makes sense -- but wouldn't the normalizing factor for $p(h_i | \boldsymbol{v})$ be dependent on $i$, then? Also -- not sure if this is a mistake or not, but you change the subscript over the sum from $i$ to $j$ partway through the derivation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53105/discussion-between-taylor-and-alias-user).